# How to remove space before replaced word in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

Autohotkey obviously needs to know where a word starts, so that it knows what to replace, just like it needs an ending character. E.g. if I have the code `::hotlb::⟦`, then `a_hotlb_a` won't be replaced but `a_ hotlb _a` will.
The thing this question is about is those two spaces this introduces.

I can get rid of the trailing right space by using `:o:hotlb::⟦`. That means I can type `a_ hotlb _a` and will get `a_ ⟦_a`. But how can I get rid of the left space?
I still want to have to type it, but I would like it to disappear after the word is replaced, so that I can type `a_ hotlb _a` and will get `a_⟦_a`.

The reason I want this is because Microsoft OneNote does not feature all latex symbols in math mode and sometimes, the spaces annoy me - but I don't want to always delete them by hand.

(If this question was already asked, please tell me what keywords you used to search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:*:hotlb::⟦
```

*** (asterisk)**: An ending character (e.g. space, period, or enter) is not required to trigger the hotstring.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options

**EDIT:**

```
:*?:hotlb::⟦
```

**? (question mark)**: The hotstring will be triggered even when it is inside another word. Use ?0 to turn this option back off.

The :o:hotsting:: - option still requires an ending character.

Try also:

```
:o?: hotlb::⟦
```

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong or this still requires a space at the start (?) So what is the difference to `:o:hotlb::⟦`?

Comment: Try also `:o?: hotlb::⟦`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit. I have tried `:o: hotlb::⟦` and that doesn't work, but your answer inspired me to try `:o?:hotlb::⟦`(with question mark but **no space** ) and this **does** work. Thanks again :) if you edit that into the answer I'll accept it

Comment: The `:*?:hotlb::⟦` does also work btw. I just prefer this other one because I can still write words containing hotlb , but I mean I can still accept your answer already